# How can I optimize let's encrypt to have very low latency

Tags: php, apache, ssl, latency

Hello I have a site hosted in us region. I have let's encrypt ssl .
I am from India and when I request the site, I see lot of ssl latency even after first byte .

I have done oscp stapling , ssl session caching and also tried to use http 2 but still no fix!

How does big sites like Netflix Bing Google Yahoo does that, not having any ssl latency after the first byte to any part of the domain

Comment: How do you know your problem is due to SSL, or even latency?

Comment: I checked with chrome network inspect element the ssl time was much more then the server wait latency